# How to get rid of Incremental annotation processing requested warning?

Tags: android, android-room, android-lifecycle

I have just started using android development and trying to use Room library. Since yesterday I am facing this warning message

> w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is
>   disabled because the following processors are not incremental:
>   androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL),
>   androidx.room.RoomProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).

I have tried to research and fix but unable to avoid this error here is my grale.build file. please suggest/advice what I am doing wrong.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ps.room.bookkeeper"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // life cycle dependencies
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    //Room dependencies
    //def room_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0'
    kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.1.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.1.0'

//    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$room_version"
//    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
//    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"

    //implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    //annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: why is your annotationProcessor commented? Did you try to uncomment them and then build project? (for both room and lifecycle)

Comment: @FerhatErgün, yes I tried also with annotationProcessor uncommented but even then no luck.

Comment: try to add android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in your gradle.properities https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ai92pt/whats_the_state_of_incremental_annotation found on this, it might be related to your problem

Comment: @FerhatErgün, appreciate you are trying to help me out but still no luck

Comment: You can downgrade kotlin-gradle-plugin in your project build.gradle file to version 1.3.41 for the time being. I think it is a bug related to kapt.
More info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33515

Comment: i am having the same problem after updating to 1.3.50

Comment: You can also create a gradle.properties file in libs/<your module name> with `kapt.incremental.apt=false` too as described in the issue as a workaround. It worked for me.

Comment: @Necrontyr, your suggestion really worked out. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is a bug in kotlin-gradle-plugin version of 1.3.50 as @Necrontyr mentioned. Just downgrade the kotlin_version in build.gradle(Project) to 1.3.41.

Comment: The bug mentioned by @Necrontyr is unrelated to the warning. The warning is actually intended and going down to 1.3.41 just hides the warning but the problem stays the same, if not worse.
People might think that because they turned on incremental annotation processing it will make things faster. But the truth is that if any of the annotation processors are not incremental then none of them will be processed incrementally. This is a friendly reminder that will point out what library is the culprit.

Comment: Using an outdated library version isn't a solution.

Comment: Is this still the case with Kotlin `1.3.70`?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.3.72 and still face this problem?

Comment: I am also facing this issue 1.3.72 any solution guys ?

Answer (score 215):

Just add this line to you gradle.properties:

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

Comment: This is a better option that the accepted answer. For those who need to understand and get into more details, refer this link : https://medium.com/avast-engineering/making-incremental-kapt-work-speed-up-your-kotlin-projects-539db1a771cf

Comment: faild for me too.

Comment: is anyone whats the reason why it's happening here?

Comment: I recently enabled data binding to my android (kotlin) project and started getting this warning. Adding the property as stated above worked for me. Also using the latest versions of everything, e.g. all dependencies, compilers, build tools, SDKs, etc.

Comment: Doing just this, did not work for me. I had to also edit my build.gradle file as described in the [documentation for the Room library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#compiler-options).

Answer (score 159):

The real problem is that incremental processing makes things faster, but if any of the annotation processors are non incremental, none of them will be actually processed in that way.

**What's the purpose of incremental processing?**

From [version *1.3.30+*](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/), incremental processing allowed modules not to be entirely processed again each time a change occurs, giving the build process a better performance:

> The main areas of focus for this release have been around
> Kotlin/Native, KAPT performance, as well as improvements for IntelliJ
> IDEA.

From [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html):

> Annotation processors (see JSR 269) are supported in Kotlin with the
> kapt compiler plugin. In a nutshell, you can use libraries such as
> Dagger or Data Binding in your Kotlin projects.

**How to fix Room Incremental Processing?**

Room incremental annotation processor is **disabled** by default. This is a known issue and it's described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112110217). They intend to fix it on version 2.2.0. You can just wait for the update or you can enable that to get rid of the warning by setting:

in *gradle.properties* file:

`kapt.incremental.apt=true`

**(optional steps)**

to allow *databinding* to be incremental:

`android.databinding.incremental=true`

for faster builds:

`kapt.use.worker.api=true`

if only a few changes are made, the build time greatly decreases:

`kapt.include.compile.classpath=false`

**(back to the subject)**

in your project *build.gradle*, add the necessary dependencies (Groovy):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-rc01"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-rc01"
}
```

and

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.incremental":"true"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kotlin DSL version:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-rc01")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-rc01")
}
```

and

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = mapOf("room.incremental" to "true")
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

*October 9, 2019*

androidx.room:room-*:2.2.0 [is released](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.2.0).

> Gradle Incremental Annotation Processor: Room is now a Gradle
> isolating annotation processor and incrementability can be enabled via
> the processor option room.incremental.

**Latest update:**

For the newest Kotlin DSL versions, please use

```
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments["room.incremental"] = "true"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one should be accepted as kapt.incremental.apt=true is something that will be missing when including Room in your project. That one is not even mentioned in Android docs for [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies)

Comment: This answer helped me as I was using `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions` in version 2.1.0 and after switching to 2.2.0-beta01 the warning went away!

Comment: @simne7 check out my edit in the end. version 2.2.0 is released =) you can upgrade it already to access the incremental processing feature and boost your build.

Comment: Would enabling `android.buildcache=true` make it faster?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky according to Google Developers Website, `Projects using Android plugin 2.3.0 and higher enable the build cache by default (unless you explicitly disable the build cache)`. So it doesn't make sense to enable it as it is enabled by default.

Answer (score 41):

From [Room documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room):

"Room has the following annotation processor options...room.incremental: Enables Gradle incremental annotation proccesor."

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                    "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                    "room.incremental":"true",
                    "room.expandProjection":"true"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to update the room version to 2.2.x or higher.

Comment: Correct answer people, if you want to keep incremental processing. You might not need schemaLocation or expandProjection arguments set above. 
room.incremental suffice.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room, there is 2.2.0-rc01 version still.

Comment: its out now --> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_220_3

Comment: Update the room version to 2.2.0    this worked for me

Answer (score 32):

## Enable Kapt Incremental annotation processing requeste

**Use Kotlin 1.3.31 or newer** [**Kotlin 1.3.30 released**](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/)

In your android kotlin project gradle.properties file

```
# Enable Kapt Incremental annotation processing requeste
kapt.incremental.apt=true

# Enable android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding (DYNAMIC)
android.databinding.incremental=true

# Decrease gradle builds time 
kapt.use.worker.api=true

# turn off AP discovery in compile path, and therefore turn on Compile Avoidance
kapt.include.compile.classpath=false

# Enable In Logcat to determine Kapt
kapt.verbose=true
```

Comment: What about `android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true`?

Answer (score 30):

Here is a list of things you can do to fix this and significantly decrease your build times while you're at it.

In your `build.gradle` (module) file:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        kapt {
            arguments {
                 arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
                 arg("room.incremental", "true")
                 arg("room.expandProjection", "true")
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In your `gradle.properties` file:

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true            // enabled by default on 1.3.50+
kapt.use.worker.api=true             // faster builds
kapt.include.compile.classpath=false // near instant builds when there are few changes

android.databinding.incremental=true
android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true
//add your specific library if it supports incremental kapt
```

Answer (score 10):

A lot of the other answers here cover up the error or disable incremental processing instead of actually making it work the way you want.

You can enable incremental processing for your specific library in the `gradle.properties` file. Just add these settings, or whichever one matches the library that throws the error:

```
android.databinding.incremental=true
android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true
```

Comment: I am not so sure about `android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true`, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere

Comment: I am not sure either, but I tried it on a hunch and the compiler stopped telling me that the lifecycleProcessor library did not have incremental processing enabled.

Answer (score 9):

If it's complaining that "Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental", then setting "kapt.incremental.apt" to "true" (mentioned in a different answer) in gradle.properties is counter-intuitive. You need to set it to "false". That did it for me.

Comment: THIS actually worked. Set it to FALSE people! thanks

Comment: And what will happen? Will it compile faster or simply hide the warning?

Comment: @CoolMind You would be disabling incremental annotation processing, something that is anyway not going to happen if any of your dependencies don't support it. So, the warning goes away and there's no change in the build process from before.

Comment: Surprisingly  setting `kapt.incremental.apt=false` helped me, I no more getting the error

Comment: You have no more error but now you have no incremental processing :)

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder and for anyone else who comes by this comment ... if you were getting the above warning, you were _already_ without incremental processing. If you end up updating your other modules and you got them all to support incremental processing, _then_ you could go back and set the line to true (or remove it entirely) so that incremental annotation processing is requested again.

Comment: +1 The only logical answer. Warning tells, that some feature was requested, but is not supported. The only thing we can do it "not to request this feature".

Answer (score 2):

What you really should do is to implement these lines of code in your `buildConfig` tag in your `build.gradle`, module app:

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.schemaLocation"  : "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental"     : "true",
                        "room.expandProjection": "true"]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), but It guess it's the same for `android.arch.lifecycle`. For me it simply helped replacing this:

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

... with this:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

So if you're using `android.arch.lifecycle` it might have the same effect replacing this:

```
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

... with this:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

Be aware that this only works if you're using Java 8 and that you also should remove [`OnLifecycleEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/OnLifecycleEvent) annotations for [`LifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver.html) classes and let those observers implement [`DefaultLifecycleObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver) instead.

Changing to this method is also recommended in the `build.gradle` depencies shown [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

Comment: Why are you getting rid of `kapt`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky That is what is suggested by the AndroidX Lifecycle if you're using Java 8. See more here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies

Comment: `kapt` is essential for Kotlin

Comment: Only if the lib requires it. According to this page the annotations will be deprecated once Java 8 get more mainstream on Android, so they recommend `common-java8` if possible: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle

Comment: Interesting.  They don't mention `kapt` in particular though...

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but in the other link they're pretty clear about using `common-java8` *instead* of `lifecycle-compiler` if using Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Above answers can be useful, but what helped me is reducing the `kotlin_version` in `build.gradle(Project)` to `1.3.41` and building the project. This will allow you to see if there is any issue with your entity model.

Mine was, I forgot to annotate `@PrimaryKey`. Your may be something different. Kotlin `1.3.41` allows to to see those issues. Fix those issues and revert back your `kotlin_version` to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 1.3.30, *kapt* supports incremental annotation processing as an experimental feature. Yet, starting from version 1.3.50, incremental annotation processing is **enabled by default**.

So, you must add `kapt.incremental.apt=true` line to your `gradle.properties` file to enable incremental annotation processing if your *kapt* version is greater than or equal to 1.3.30 and lower than 1.3.50. Otherwise; you don't have to set `kapt.incremental.apt` to `true` to enable it. Although, you can set it to `false` to disable it if you like.

Besides all of that; **incremental annotation processing requires incremental compilation to be enabled** as well. So, you must add `kotlin.incremental=true` line to your `gradle.properties` file to be able to benefit from incremental annotation processing feature.

Note that incremental annotation processing option of Room is **ON by default** starting from version 2.3.0-alpha02. It means you don't have to set `room.incremental` argument to `true` if your version of the library is greater than or equal to this. To learn more, see [issue #112110217](https://issuetracker.google.com/112110217).

Also note that if you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.x or newer, incremental annotation processing option is **ON by default** for Data Binding. So, you don't have to add `android.databinding.incremental=true` line to your `gradle.properties` file. To learn more, see [issue #110061530](https://issuetracker.google.com/110061530).

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by character problems such as "*İ*" on the *databinding* side when the system language is a non-English language. In such a case, using the computer system language in English will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for me this is happen when my entity with primay key and  @NonNull annotation, but type field still using nullable (?). so, just remove this ?, the problem is gone

```
data class TvEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNull
        @ColumnInfo(name = "tvId")
        var tvId: String?,
```