# The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated, room.incremental]'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
w: warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated, room.incremental]'
```

Why am I getting this? I am using Room in a multi module project.

- Kotlin version: 1.3.50
- AGP: 3.5.0
- Room: 2.2.0-rc01

Shared libraries module:
    `api "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    api "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    api "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"`

App module:

`kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`

Gradle.properties

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
```

Build.gradle defaultConfig includes [these compile options](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room):

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            arguments = ["room.incremental":"true"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is room annotation processor is added?

Comment: Thanks Kaushik I think you've pointed me in the right direction.  I edited the answer to reflect that those dependencies are specified in one module, and an app module features the annotation processor. Possibly I am specifying the flags in modules which do not use the processor

Comment: i think the solution is to configure the build.gradle of the module that contains the RoomDatabase derived class.

Comment: Yes this is the key, so even if a module has the dependencies and annotation processor but doesn't use them, it seems to produce this warning. If you leave this as an answer I will accept, maybe it will help someone :)

Comment: Yes sure! I will add these as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of problem can occure with a multi-module project that has been added to room. For such a project the problem was caused by adding the RoomDatabase derived class to a library module, but configuring the build.gradle of app module.

The solution is to configure the build.gradle of the module that contains the RoomDatabase derived class.

- In the build.gradle file in the dependencies{} section add the dependency for the room compiler.

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Note that for java based project use below code

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that missing kapt in module was the original problem in IDE.

- "androidx.room:room-compiler:${roomVersion}"

There can be other one in CLI, which you can see with verbose warnings:

> Current JDK version 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12 has a bug
>   (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room
>   from being incremental. Consider using JDK 11+ or the embedded JDK
>   shipped with Android Studio 3.5+.warning: The following options were
>   not recognized by any processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated,
>   room.incremental]'[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested,
>   but support is disabled because the following processors are not
>   incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).

Comment: Did you happen to fix the jdk version bug issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before: what did I do?

First, in build.gradle file in the object called defaultConfig I have to delete:

```
javaCompileOptions {
    annotationProcessorOptions {
        arguments = ["room.incremental":"true"]
    }
}
```

I have to replace:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

With:

```
// Room components
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
kaptAndroidTest "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"

// Lifecycle components
def archLifecycleVersion = "2.2.5"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$archLifecycleVersion"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$archLifecycleVersion"
```

Second, in gradle.properties I add:

```
kapt.incremental.apt=true
kapt.use.worker.api=true
android.lifecycleProcessor.incremental=true
```

See [related problem in other stack overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670510/how-to-get-rid-of-incremental-annotation-processing-requested-warning) about this configuration.