# How to get rid of Incremental annotation processing requested warning during the build?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm

I have just started using android development.  I am facing this warning message

> [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor (NON_INCREMENTAL).

I got a warning when I was programming with the book as a reference. I've looked into several solutions and tried, but couldn't find a solution. Please give me some advice.

[How to get rid of Incremental annotation processing requested warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670510/how-to-get-rid-of-incremental-annotation-processing-requested-warning)
This link is the page I referred to.

Here's my build.gradle(Modules: app) files.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matsu.bloodpressure"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

build.gradles file↓

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.1.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradles.properties file↓

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Comment: Incremental annotation processing support was added in 5.11.0. You are using 5.1.0. I don't remember the changelogs per version as well as I used to, so you might want to check the changelog to see what changed over time. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: If you are NOT using the Realm Sync functionality (`Realm Object Server`), then you should be safe to update to 6.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Realm-Java 5.1.0.

Incremental annotation processing was added to Realm in 5.11.0.

You should try to update to 6.1.0, the only breaking change was in regards to the Realm Object Server PermissionManager API, which you probably aren't using, but contains important bug fixes like the 6.0.1 fix regarding encrypted Realms.