# Gradle - "Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes."

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

When running my LibGDX desktop project I sometimes get this error:

`Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes.`

I've tried using Java 8 and 17. I'm using Gradle 7.4.2.

I've tried the changes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670510/how-to-get-rid-of-incremental-annotation-processing-requested-warning) but they seem to be for a Kotlin project.

I'm struggling to find any more info on what is causing this.

What else can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This problem occurred for me because my project files were located within a OneDrive folder. To solve this issue; I right-clicked on my project folder in explorer and selected "Always keep on this device".

--EDIT, 8/12/2022--
Longer term I've found actually that it didn't fully work and I ended up abandoning trying to keep it on OneDrive.

Comment: Did not solve for me. I always have to clean the project since the last Android studio update

Comment: "Always keep on this device" solved for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

I also received this error message after successfully building the project a few times. "Build / Clean Project" solved.

Comment: Is it possible to add more steps on how to achieve the clean and also support it with screenshots

Comment: I think he meant Build and Clean tasks in Gradle

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix my error by going to `File` and clicking `Reload all from Disk`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `File` > `Reload all from Disk` is an action that is possible when you use IntelliJ. I have tried this but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it would not let me just clean the gradle. I solved it by deleting my `/android` folder and running the build command afresh.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22002) that occurs eventually for me associated to *Onedrive* backup. For me set `"Always keep on this device"` on in *OneDrive* doesn't solve it.

I also noticed that this event is intermittent and probabilistic, being especially common in small and rapid source changes.

While the *JetBrains* team doesn't fix this problem, I simply pause the *OneDrive* sync in adjustments (gear icon) and few minutes later I resume it. It's a kind of trick, but it works and  it's fast.

**Update**: Neither when I pause *OneDrive* works in all situations. I try everything, include invalidate caches. When I take out the folder from *OneDrive* it works. I will update it here if the problem returns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the main reason that message shows up its because you have to save all your changes. Sometimes i forgot to save all changes and when rebuilding or rerunning that message appears to me too. That solves, in my case, the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue in WSL ubuntu, it was caused by some files in sources are not readable (permissions 000), change them to 644 then build ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and tried everything on this thread without success. Android Studio tells to try to build with `--info` to try and catch the problem, I tried and it turns out I had copied an invisible file (0 kb) to the assets and that broke the build.

My answer is not very helpful as is but it may steer the person who reads this in the right direction.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32772576)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue on my PC was that Windows defender detected a project build file as a threat.
You can either deal with the threat in the code or, if you trust that code you can ignore that threat in the antivirus software.

Answer (score 0):

use flutter clean
then when the process end run the project again

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked is just to move the file from the "one Drive" folder to the "Local Disc" folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem after i restart my android studio because my caches are corrupted.
i solved it by cleaning project.

Build -> Clean project.