# Flutter Error Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Changes are not tracked, unable determine incremental changes.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803147/gradle-changes-are-not-tracked-unable-determine-incremental-changes Seems to be a few options to try.